# JavaScript timed loop rounding error

Tags: javascript, console.log, timedelay

```
timedLoop(10000, function() {
  health=health-0.1;
  updatecounters();
  console.log(health);
});
```

Health is initially set to 83.3 and console.log prints out the following statements:

```
83.2
83.10000000000001
83.00000000000001
82.90000000000002
82.80000000000003
82.70000000000003
82.60000000000004
82.50000000000004
82.40000000000005
```

It's supposed to be decreasing by 0.1 every 10 seconds, but there seems to be a floating point error. I know that I can fix this by simply rounding the variable to 2 decimal places, but why does this happen?

I think that this is just shitty compiling. If a number has a terminating decimal (less than 32 digits) or is rational, the program should be able to store the exact value instead of making shenanigans like these happen. I fully understand why multiplication and division induce floating point errors, but addition and subtraction should not cause bugs like these.

Comment: Downfall of javascript.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir can you explain this? All I got when googling was an irrelevant video and some articles about advantages and disadvantages of Javascript.

Comment: How would YOU exactly represent 0.1 in binary, then?

Comment: Javascript is not so great when it comes to math.

Comment: Same thing happens if you do this in python. It has to do with how floats are stored, nothing to do with the interpreter.

Comment: Related: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: For the most part you can ignore the rounding error. It is very small, if Earth is 1 unit wide then your error is the size of an atom in comparison, for most situations, Insignificant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not with javascript but it applies to all floating point calculations since 0.1 and 0.2 and 0.3 are not exactly representable.

[Check this link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) to know more about it

Comment: While it makes sense that Javascript uses base 2 for floating point representations in general, it should use base 10 for mathematical operations.

Comment: @Displayname Computers pretty much run on base 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can called .toFixed on the number after the subtraction.

```js
let health = 83.3;

setInterval(function() {
  health = (health - 0.1).toFixed(1);
  console.log(health);
}, 500);
```

However, `.toFixed` will convert the number to a string, if you need to keep it as a number, you can wrap the code with the number constructor:

```
Number((health - 0.1).toFixed(1));
```

Comment: You should mention that `health` becomes a string.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir, great point. Can be a good "gotcha" if not careful

Answer (score 0):

Floating point issues are just part of life. You need to learn to live with them.

You could try:

```
// health (String) is for display, can be values from 100.0 to 0.1
var health = "100.0";
// healthMath (Int) is for calculations. It is an int, not a float. 
var healthMath = 1000;
```

So, in your example:

```
timedLoop(10000, function() {
  healthMath -= 1;
  health = (healthMath / 10).toFixed(1);
  updatecounters();
  console.log(health);
});
```